# Variadic class method with a virtual base class

Tags: c++, c++11, entity-component-system

I am trying to change my component pool generator to use variadic templates in an attempt to avoid all the Init() functions and use each component constructor instead. However I can't get it to compile.

This is the component pool class, it has a base class and its methods will be overriden by the parent class:

```
class iComponentPool
{
public:
    virtual iComponent* Create(EntityId entityId) = 0;
    virtual iComponent* Get(EntityId entityId) = 0;
    virtual void Destroy(EntityId entityId) = 0;
};

template<typename T>
class componentIterator
{
public:
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator beginIT;
    typename std::vector<T>::iterator endIT;

};

template<typename T, typename ... Targs>
class componentPool : public iComponentPool, public componentIterator<T>
{
public:
    T* Create(EntityId entityID, Targs... Args) override
    {
    };

    T* Get(EntityId entityId) override 
    { 
        return nullptr;
    };

    void Destroy(EntityId entityId) override 
    {
    };
};
```

However the compiler complains (and rightfully so) that the componentPool Create method is not overriding the base class method. Is there any way to get around this problem?

The actual error (VS 2015) is:

```
'ECS::componentPool<T,statics::staticAsset *&>::Create':
  method with override specifier 'override' did not override any base class methods
```

Comment: When you override a parent-class function, you need to use the exact signature of the function in the parent class. Otherwise you can always *overload* the function.

Comment: If you want your `iComponentPool` to `Create` instances of `iCompoment`, I think you should have a look at the factory design pattern.

Comment: What is your plan for when someone has only an `iComponent` pointer (and can only call that base class's `Create`) to pass any additional arguments that the actual implementation(s) of `Create` in the derived class need? That cannot work.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes i know, it worked fine before when i didnt have the variadic template because the signatures matched.

Comment: @linuxfever Yep thats exactly what i want to do, and its working without the varidiac template. The actual pattern is: a `componentsManager` creates `componentPool` s which then creates `iComponent`s. I guess i can take a look at that patten. Thanks!

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude That was my thought initially but you cant do templates with virtual functions unfortunately.